# How to give a background color for a single letter with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following div elements.

```
<div class="de">d</div>
<div class="es">e</div>
<div class="si">s</div>
<div class="ig">i</div>
<div class="gn">g</div>
<div class="ns">n</div>
```

I'd like to apply a background color to some of the divs.

I have tried below code:

```
.si {background-color: #00ff00}
```

Although, this gave it a background color but only one third of the letter was covered.

`S` and `I` both have background-color 00ff00 but only a third of each letter is covered.

Page [here](http://4309.co.uk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give a background colour to multiple classes, you can add attributes to multiple classes by separating them as commas, like so:

```css
.si,
.gn {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

You can also add backgrounds to groups (such as all `<div>` tags) like so:

```
div {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Or even just `<div>` tags with a `class` attribute

```
div[class] {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

**Edit:**
From the comment below, to ensure that the `s` is fully covered by the background, you need to ensure the `line-height` is higher. Currently, you have a `font-size` of `300px` for the font, but no `line-height` set, so the `line-height` of the font is inherited from the closest parent with a line-height set. This is probably just the default line height of the document (usually ~18px or so).

To fix this, either set the line height of the element to be relative to the font size (such as `line-height: 1em` or `line-height: 1.2em`) or set the line-height explicitly (such as `line-height: 320px`).

Note that `em` units are relative, with `1` being the same as the font-size and effectively 100%, and decimals being allowed.

Comment: Thanks. But why is only a third of the `S` covered when I give it a background color?

Comment: This is because the `s` has a default line height that's probably around `18px` or so, depending on the font size of the `body` tag, yet has a font size of `300px`. You need to change the `line-height` for the `s` to be either `1em` (so it is relative to the font size) or set an explicit `line-height` like `300px`

Comment: So I set line-height to normal, why does it have such large padding?

Comment: Because setting `line-height: normal` sets the line-height to the default, which is usually between 110% and 120% (so 1.1em - 1.2em). When you have `font-size: 300px` this means that the line-height will be around 330px - 360px, adding between 15-30px spacing above and below the font. You can make this tighter by changing the line-height to `1em` rather than `normal`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to play around with this? Like 0.5em?

Comment: Yes, you can have any value for `em`, including `0.5em`

Comment: OK. Because using 0.7em for example simply expands the green space above the letter and reduces it below. Is there a way to match it exactly?

Comment: Like altering width/height of background color?

Comment: That's because line-height is based on a capital letter, and the `s` is lowercase, so not 'full-height'. If you want this to be exact, you may be best placed using an SVG image with a character inside, instead of a plain text character, and having a box within the SVG too. This should get you started - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

Answer (score 1):

Just give `line-height: normal;` in [4309.co.uk](http://4309.co.uk/) as you are changing the `font-size`.

```
.si {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

In your case, the `line-height` was specified to `24px`, and since the `font-size` exceeds that height, the rest of the content is cut off. See the example below.

```css
.big {
  font-size: 5em;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.normal {
  top: 150px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="text big">
  Sample Text
</div>

<div class="text big normal">
  Sample Text
</div>
```

Comment: That worked. But why does it have such big padding then?

Comment: @user11963881 have updated the post with explanation.

Comment: @user11963881 where is the padding?

Comment: Not padding but a large amount of green space and not cropped neatly around the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding special class to letters you want to have background-color makes it. I've also added `display: inline` to divs, so that letters display, well, inline. That's if you *really* want `div` for each letter. I suggest using `span`, which by default has `display: inline` (snippet 2).

#### Snippet 1 -- with `<div>`:

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}

.coloredLetter {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="de">d</div>
<div class="es coloredLetter">e</div>
<div class="si">s</div>
<div class="ig coloredLetter">i</div>
<div class="gn">g</div>
<div class="ns coloredLetter">n</div>
```

#### Snippet 2 -- with `<span>`:

```css
.coloredLetter {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<span class="de">d</span>
<span class="es coloredLetter">e</span>
<span class="si">s</span>
<span class="ig coloredLetter">i</span>
<span class="gn">g</span>
<span class="ns coloredLetter">n</span>
```

Comment: Yes, but please see page http://4309.co.uk. Why is only a third of the s covered?

Comment: Because you've explicitly added `background-color: #00ff00;` to it's styles.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using marker for something like this.

Example

```
<mark class="si">D<mark>

.si { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

This will make the whole background of the letter colourised.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline method, this is what its for!....

```
This <style="color:blue;">is</style> what its for....
```